# Телеграмм бот не считывает текст, введенный пользователем

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Это пример кода, который должен принимать значение нового имени, и менять его, но сохраняется в новое имя значение /name. Пробовал использовать slice(5), но тоже ничего не выходит. Если возможно дайте какой-нибудь пример, где пользователь что-нибудь вводит, и бот это понимает.

```py
bot.on('text', async (ctx) => {
    let userId = ctx.message.from.id;

    let usersData = await usersSchema.findOne({
        id: userId
    });

    if (!usersData || usersData === null || usersData === undefined) {
        await usersSchema.create({
            id: userId
        });
    }

    console.log('Информация о пользователе:', usersData);

    if (ctx.message.text === '/name') {
        ctx.reply(`Пожалуйста, введите новое имя:`).then(async () => {
            let userName = ctx.message.text;

            if (userName) {
                usersData.name = userName;
                await usersData.save();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так, ты не проверял второе сообщение где указано имя…

```
bot.on('text', async (ctx) => {
  let userId = ctx.message.from.id;
  let usersData = await usersSchema.findOne({ id: userId });

  if (!usersData || usersData === null || usersData === undefined) {
    await usersSchema.create({ id: userId });
  }

  console.log('Информация о пользователе:', usersData);

  if (ctx.message.text === '/name') {
    ctx.reply('Пожалуйста, введите новое имя:');

    // Ожидание следующего сообщения от пользователя
    bot.on('text', async (ctx) => {
      let userName = ctx.message.text;
      if (userName) {
        usersData.name = userName;
        await usersData.save();
        ctx.reply(`Ваше имя успешно сохранено: ${userName}`);
      } else {
        ctx.reply('Вы не ввели имя.');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Все равно запоминает /name :(